# Is it possible to have the url change while you scroll down a single page

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, url-rewriting

Is it possible to have the url change while you scroll down a single page with ajax? I have a website all on one page and want to have this effect.

example:

```
www.blablabla.com/blog
```

user scroll down...

```
www.blablabla.com/blog/entry-name
```

I know about hashing... can I mask the URL?

Comment: I'm curious to see where this goes but my gut feel is it's a _bad practice_.  So, if I'm looking at the said blabla blog home page and scrolling down several posts, my address bar will dynamically change so that when I copy and paste that URL to a friend they will see the page at the same bookmark/scroll position?

Comment: yes this is what I would like to happen.

Comment: better cross your fingers on this one...

Comment: I found this: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scroll-link-nav.html#third     But I feel like it might not work well with a page that has a ton of content on it.

Comment: I checked that out in chrome but it didn't change the url as I scrolled, only visibly changed the link buttons css, which was cool...  I guess.

Comment: You can now. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 31):

I know this is a bit of an older question, but browsers changed, and right now, it is possible to do what the poster requested. This means that most of the other answers are no longer valid. I'm posting a way to accomplish this so that it might help people using Google to find the correct answer.

In short, on modern browsers (browsers with HTML 5 support) you can. Please have a look at [this](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) article.

It basically boils down to the following line of code:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Executing the above code will change the URL to example.com/new-url, and will help you accomplish what you wanted.

For a demo, you can take a look at the [Webby Awards](http://winners.webbyawards.com/2013/online-film-video/general-film-categories/drama), where this method is used. Just scroll up or down and look at the address bare. The effect is pretty impressive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was exactly i was looking for. Another nice example: rollingstone.com/music/lists/15-great-albums-you-didnt-hear-in-2014-20141217

Answer (score 6):

You can use pushState() to modify the URL displayed in the browser URL bar without reloading or using the hash. As long as your browser supports HTML5 that is.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 4):

No. Not sure why you would want to either.

As you mentioned, the only way would be to add it on to the page's hash, ex.

```
http://www.website.com/blog/#entry-name
```

Then to scroll to that part of the page, something like:

```
if (window.location.indexOf("#") > 0) {
    var entry_id = window.location.substring(window.location.indexOf("#"));
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(entry_id).offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

**EDIT: This is long since possible with `window.history.pushState`.**

Comment: I would want to do that so that when a blog post is shared it would be positioned in the correct spot on the page.

Comment: so I could mask that url from www.homepage.com/blog/#entryname to www.homepage.com/blog/entryname

Comment: Please check http://winners.webbyawards.com/2013/online-film-video/general-film-categories/drama or my answer below, and scroll up or down. So yes, this is certainly possible. Then again, now it's 2013 ;)

Answer (score 0):

what about https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/[history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Including continued support for data, titles, replaceState. Supports jQuery, MooTools and Prototype. For HTML5 browsers this means that you can modify the URL directly, without needing to use hashes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible using window.pushState method.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can, but it's a little tricky.

If you have this on your `index.html` page:

```
  <a id="link-to-later" href="#later">Go to later</a>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p> 
  <a id="later" name="later">Some later anchor</a>
```

Then clicking the top link will take you to the anchor below without reloading the page and the url will be `index.html#later`.

By using the `window.onscroll` event you can hook an event to the user scrolling down the page.  The event handler could include something like `$('#link-to-later').click()`, which would send the user's browser to point on the page with the `later` anchor.

You will need to do some work to keep this from being too choppy, but it is doable.

Comment: didn't see @dtbarne's answer before - check that one out

Answer (score -2):

No, for security reasons you are not allowed to change the URL using javascript

Comment: Actually you are not allowed to change it without refreshing.

Comment: well by changing the URL you could trick the user to think they are on a website that they are really not. Like they visit www.blablabla.com/blog and you change the URL to www.yourbank.com they could believe they are actually viewing their bank website.