# How can I change the url when the page refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example,
When you click a tag which is linked to an `ID` value in the same page,
URL is changed like this : `index.html#content04`.
But, since I use scroll event that shows headers of each sector when mouse wheel is scrolled down, I want to make the URL default just like `index.html` to hide all the headers of each section so that I can see them only when I scroll down.
How do I make a script for this?

URL : `index.html#content04. -> index.html` // when refreshed

Comment: Are you using a javascript library that provides a means to scroll to an element using Javascript?  If so, call that method in the onclick handler for the links in question, like `<a href="#sometag" onclick="scrollto(this.href.substr(1)); return false;">SomeTag</a>`.  Your target would look like: `<a name="sometag" id="sometag">SomeTag Target</a>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have the url change while you scroll down a single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146560/is-it-possible-to-have-the-url-change-while-you-scroll-down-a-single-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) object:

```
if (location.hash) {
    location.href = location.href.substr(0, location.href.indexOf('#'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with suggestion on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16337643/1450348?stw=2

Answer (score 0):

you can use preventdefault() Ex. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ 
 or 
use return false; as @J.D. Pace mentioned