# How to change page url while you scroll down a single page for a WordPress blog?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to achieve something like what [Webby Awards](http://www.webbyawards.com/winners/2013/) have done on their webpage.

I did refer one of the of the questions [Is it possible to have the url change while you scroll down a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146560/is-it-possible-to-have-the-url-change-while-you-scroll-down-a-single-page) but could not understand a way to integrate the same in WordPress.

I want to integrate this in a WordPress blog. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain more in-depth what you tried such that the question is not so dependent on external sites.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146560/is-it-possible-to-have-the-url-change-while-you-scroll-down-a-single-page

This may help you.

Comment: @Ajay have you read OP Question? OP provide the same link that you pasted.

Comment: @Kabahango I tried looking out for a plugin but could not find any. I'm just a beginner in WordPress so couldn't really understand how to archive this. If you could let me know how to integrate this in WordPress would be really appreciated!

Comment: So you're asking how to add JavaScript to a WordPress blog?

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="height:500px">div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="height:500px">div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="height:500px">div3</div>
<div id="div4" style="height:500px">div4</div>
```

JS

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#div1")) { window.history.pushState("state", "title", "/div1"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#div2")) { window.history.pushState("state", "title", "/div2"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#div3")) { window.history.pushState("state", "title", "/div3"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#div4")) { window.history.pushState("state", "title", "/div4"); return; }
});
```

OR

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > some_number) {
        // change url here
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do it. May be by enabling Ajax?