# How do I replace the URL when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a page with articles. As soon as the page finishes, another article is loaded from another file.

Each uploaded file has an attribute `data-url="/url..."`. How can I display this url when I upload a new article in scroll?

For example: there is a page with url `example.com/data/article.html` and when the page is scrolled down the new file is loaded and the url changes to `example.com/data/articleNext.html` without rebooting.

There is an _url variable in the code and you can do this with it, but how do I spell it correctly?

**An example script to load a new scroll page:**

```js
'use strict';

var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
var $article_list = $('#article_list');
var sticky = 0;
var send = true;
var page = {
  init: function init() {
    var top = page.getScrollTop();

  },

  getScrollTop: function() {
    if (typeof pageYOffset != 'undefined') {
      //most browsers except IE before #9
      return pageYOffset;
    } else {
      var B = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
      var D = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
      D = D.clientHeight ? D : B;
      return D.scrollTop;
    }
  },
  scrollPage: function() {
    var topPos = $('#get_article').offset().top;
    var top = page.getScrollTop();
    var diff = topPos - top;
    // console.log( diff +'||'+ top +'||'+ topPos);

    if ((diff <= (height - sticky)) && send) {

      var $last_article = $article_list.children().last()
      var _url = $last_article.attr('data-url');
      send = false;
      if (_url) {
        $.ajax({
          url: _url,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'html',
          beforeSend: function() {
            // включение прелоудера
            send = false;
          },
          complete: function() {
            // отключение прелоудера
          },
          success: function(obj) {
            send = true;
            $article_list.append(obj);

            const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#videoPlay')).map(p => new Plyr(p));
            const plyrs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#plyrVideo')).map(plyrs => new Plyr(plyrs));
          },
          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText + "\r\n" + xhr);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
/**
 * section init
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  page.init();
});
/**
 * section scroll animation
 */
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  page.scrollPage();

});

$(window).resize(function() {});
```

**File `article.html`:**

```html
<div class="article__article" data-url="/data/article.html">Content...</div>
```

**Content that's loaded on scroll:**

```html
<div class="article__article" data-url="/data/art2.html">Next Content...</div>
```

Tried to do it with `window.history.pushState`, but somehow it doesn't work, I guess I'm doing something wrong.

```js
if (_url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: _url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function() {
      // включение прелоудера
      send = false;
    },
    complete: function() {
      // отключение прелоудера
    },
    success: function(obj) {
      send = true;
      $article_list.append(obj);
      
      ///////
      const newUrl = "article_s.html"
      window.history.pushState({}, "", newUrl);
      ///////
      
      const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#videoPlay')).map(p => new Plyr(p));
      const plyrs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#plyrVideo')).map(plyrs => new Plyr(plyrs));
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText + "\r\n" + xhr);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have the url change while you scroll down a single page](answer-16337643)

Comment: @FluffyKitten   I tried to do something with your solution, but something doesn't work, I guess I'm doing something wrong, added an example below.

Comment: Oops, something went wrong with the url there when I tried to link directly to the best answer :) This is the link  [Is it possible to have the url change while you scroll down a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146560/is-it-possible-to-have-the-url-change-while-you-scroll-down-a-single-page#answer-16337643).

Comment: @FluffyKitten There is a code sample above, the problem is, am I not sure if I did the right thing? `const newUrl = "article_s.html" window.history.pushState({}, "", newUrl);`